# How can I view my open streams on Crunchyroll?

Tags: crunchyroll

When going to watch a show on Crunchyroll, I got the following error

> We love all your streams, but there's a limit. Continue watching on this device by closing an existing stream or upgrading your subscription.

I closed Crunchyroll on my other computer, but I'm still getting the error. Without knowing what these streams are, I can't tell if there's a delay after closing a stream, I've let other devices on, or if someone else is using my account.

How can I tell what devices are streaming on my Crunchyroll account? Is there a way to force-disconnect those sessions?

[image: Too many stream sessions open]

Answer (score 1):

I am also having this issue with CR.

i have tested this with CR with a few different devices. I have a ticket open with them and we are reviewing together.  they have stated that recent changes were made regarding to stream limits.

ive tested with multiple streams open on multiple devices. it seems to be hit or miss when this occurs. sometimes it works sometimes it doesnt.

regarding your question about how to view open streams or device that are accessing the platform.

go to My Account > Device Mangement.

this will show you devices that have access. you can deactivate devices here if needed. note that you will have to log bag into to the service on the device if you deactivate but i havent found this to be a major issue for myself.

ive tested this however and found that even if you deactivate all devices, you may still have an issue accessing the streams. CR support advised me to wait roughly 5 minutes before accessing again.

sometime it works and sometime it doesnt. its a bit strange in behavior. either way working on getting some info from CR. currently waiting on response form their support.

Comment: Any news from their CS? I’ve tried deactivating all devices and signing back in but the app just hangs on the loading screen…